# Real Time Plot with Delay instead of Breaks

Tags: javascript, plotly, real-time

I am programming a Real Time Plot with Plotly.

What should I do to correct this situation, and gaining a delay in the execution instead of breaking the sequence?

[image]

chart.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
    <div id="plot"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

chart.js

```
var time = new Date();
function setup(){
    var data = [{
        x: [time],
        y: [Math.random()],
        mode: 'lines',
        line: {color: '#80CAF6'}
    }]
    Plotly.newPlot('plot', data);
}

function loop() {
    var time = new Date();
    var t0=new Date(),tn=new Date();
    var ti=[],xi=[];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        ti[i]=new Date();
        ti[i].setTime(time.getTime()-dt*1000.0*(n-i)/n);
        xi[i]=Math.random();
    }
    t0.setTime(time.getTime()-19000);
    tn.setTime(time.getTime()+1000);
    var update = {
        x:[ti],
        y:[xi]
    };
    var minuteView = {
        xaxis: {
            type:'date',
            range:[t0,tn]
        }
      };
    Plotly.relayout('plot',minuteView);
    Plotly.extendTraces('plot',update,[0]);
    time.setTime(time.getTime()+dt*1000);
    if(++k===100) 
        clearInterval(oInt);
}

var k=0,dt=0.5,n=100,oInt;
function main(){
    setup();
    oInt=setInterval(
        loop, 
        dt*1000
    );
}
```

As all data comes with its own datetime from stable sensors, the plot should be stable, with a global delay (which we want to be as small as possible of course, but inevitably increasing in some specific situations, delay to be solved by the CPU later under some proper margin).

For this, in the loop, I tried to prepare a simulated code, keeping all the time values independent of the CPU.

Evidently, I failed. When I simulate a load increment acting over the browser windows - such as losting the tab focus, move the window, minimize or maximize the window, etc.- instead of gaining a delay, the plot lost its integrity, and "breaks" or "holes" appear.